# Kafka topic filtering vs. ephemeral topics for microservice request/reply pattern

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices

I'm trying to implement a request/reply pattern with Kafka. I am working with named services and unnamed clients that send messages to those services, and clients may expect a reply. Many (10s-100s) of clients may interact with a single service, or consumer group of services.

**Strategy one: filtering messages**

The first thought was to have two topics per service - the "HelloWorld" service would consume the "HelloWorld" topic, and produce replies back to the "HelloWorld-Reply" topic. Clients would consume that reply topic and filter on unique message IDs to know what replies are relevant to them.

The drawback there is it seems like it might create unnecessary work for clients to filter out a potentially large amount of irrelevant messages when many clients are interacting with one service.

**Strategy two: ephemeral topics**

The second idea was to create a unique ID per client, and send that ID along with messages. Clients would consume their own unique topic "[ClientID]" and services would send to that topic when they have a reply. Clients would thus not have to filter irrelevant messages.

The drawback there is clients may have a short lifespan, e.g. they may be single use scripts, and they would have to create their topic beforehand and delete it afterward. There might have to be some extra process to purge unused client topics if a client dies during processing.

*Which of these seems like a better idea?*

Comment: I have been having the same thoughts and have decided to use NATS instead as it supports the request-reply pattern by design and comes with several more benefits. https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/reqreply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using Kafka in production as a handler for event based messages and request/response messages. our approach to implementing request/response is your **first strategy** because, when the number of clients grows, you have to create many topics which some of them are completely useless. another reason for choosing the first strategy was our topic naming guideline that each service should belong to only one topic for tacking. however, Kafka is not made for request/response messages but I recommend the first strategy because:

- few numbers of topics
- better service tracking
- better topic naming

but you have to be careful about your consumer groups. which may causes of data loss.

A better approach is using the first strategy with many partitions in one topic (service) that each client sends and receives its messages with a unique key. Kafka guarantees that all messages with the same key will go to a specific partition. this approach doesn't need filtering irrelevant messages and maybe is a combination of your two strategies.

**Update:**

As @ValBonn said in the suggested approach you always have to be sure that `the number of partitions >= number of clients`.

Comment: Hi. We also use the first strategy, for the same reasons. I just wanted to react on your "better approach" proposal: the way (default) partitioning works on Kafka guarantees that all the messages with the same key go to the same partition, as you wrote. But it does not guarantee that you won't have two clients on the same partition, and then you cannot get rid of filtering irrelevant messages. An alternative would be to write a customer partitioner, that guarantees one client=one partition, but the drawback would be to maintain the number of partitions, the same case as a adding new topics....

Comment: @ValBonn Hi. Thanks for the advice. however, the drawback is the same as adding new topics but this time our topics are in a discipline.